# Angular 2 create html element with onchange

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have an app that will show a line graph with a different number of lines depending on the number of selects (1 line for each selected field, maximum of 5 selects). The first two work very well because they are the pre-defined, I can specify (change)="function". The other 3 are optional, so I have added a button that adds selects to the html. The only problem is that when I add those selects dynamically they are not assuming the onchange function which is supposed to re-draw the graphic.

Here are samples of my code:

```
add() {

      var child = document.getElementById('addField');
      var selectList = document.createElement("select");

      if (child.previousElementSibling) {
          selectList.id = "field" + (parseInt(child.previousElementSibling.id.charAt(child.previousElementSibling.id.length-1)) + 1);
          selectList.innerHTML = selectList.innerHTML + child.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
      }
      else {
          selectList.id = "field" + (parseInt(child.previousElementSibling.id.charAt(child.previousElementSibling.id.length-1)) + 1);
          selectList.innerHTML = selectList.innerHTML + child.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
      }

      if(parseInt(selectList.id.charAt(selectList.id.length-1)) > 5)
        alert("Maximum number of parameters is : 5");
      else {
        selectList.setAttribute('onchange', "drawChart()");
        child.parentNode.insertBefore(selectList, child);
      }

    }
```

This function is to add the select above the addField button and it says that drawChart doesn't exist.

The html page looks like this:

```
<div id="principal">
<label>Parameters :</label>
    <select id="field1" (change)="drawChart()">
        <option *ngFor="let pos of array"
            [value] = "pos.name"
            [selected]="pos.name == 'def'">
            {{pos.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select id="field2" (change)="drawChart()">
        <option *ngFor="let pos of array"
            [value] = "pos.name"
            [selected]="pos.name == 'def2'">
            {{pos.name}}
        </option>
        </select>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="addField" value="Add Field" (click)="add()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you writing directly to the DOM? Use a template.
"drawChart()" cannot work because you are not working on the same context, that onchange is waiting for a window.drawChart() function.

Comment: That's not the angular way to do this. You should define your dynamic elements also in your template and add some conditions to them with *ngIf="showOptional" for instance.

Comment: How can I define dynamic elements in the component? @cy3er

Comment: Yes @camaron I know they are different contexts. But I'm new to angular 2 so I was hoping someone could enlight me on this. I have a template for the graphs page and in the middle somewhere there are the selects. Where should I use the template and how?

Comment: That doesn't look like Angular at all. How is Angular involved?

Comment: @RuiPedro edit your question and add the template of the graphs page.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer well, this piece of code performs well when you put it in the <script> tag in the page in a .jsp for example. But in Angular that can't happen so you need to put it in the component. The thing is that they become different contexts, and you can't call the function drawChart in HTML after template binding because it won't recognize the function. And the selects are created dynamically when you press a button.

Comment: The question should contain the code that makes that obvious. The `add()` function in your question doesn't provide any information about a context at all. Where is it, where is it called from, how does the HTML look like it operates on, ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer well, it doesn't really matter the rest of the component for this case. As for the html template, my bad. It's already edited with it

Comment: What's the purpose of setting an `onchange` attribute when there is already a `(change)` event handler?

Comment: @camaron it's in the edit now.

Comment: I'm sorry @GünterZöchbauer but you need to read the text before making those questions. These are the two pre-defined selects as it is stated in the text of the question. The other 3 are optional and dynamic and those don't have any onchange as they are being programatically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add something like this after your last select element.

```
<select id="{{extraItem.id}}" *ngFor="let extraItem of extraFields" (change)="drawChart()">
    <option *ngFor="let child of extraItem.children"
             [value] = "child.name"
             [selected]="child.name == 'Opt 2 - 1'">
             {{child.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Check this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/p1WimIz3ygE2CSs2tmw2?p=preview

I think that you want something like this.

You want to have full control of everything from your angular app, it's better to have templates and find the way to do all without write directly to the DOM and let angular handle the DOM.

Comment: that's it! thank you very much for your help. a much cleaner code like that and I don't have to access DOM which is not very safe in angular 2.